# x86 Procedure Bugs

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I've put together a program that increments from 1 to check every number under 100, if prime, the number will be stored into an array. The problem i'm getting however is that nothing is being stored into the array and the registers aren't being utilized as intended. On it's own the '_isPrime' procedure fully works as intended, but when I piece it together with the code in the main then call it thats where the errors seem to be coming from. Are my loops implemented correctly in the main? Is there anything else I should be doing in the procedure?

```
.DATA

arr DWORD 27 DUP (?)

.CODE           
_MainProc   PROC

        mov eax, 1      ; number in eax will be prime checked / edx will be 1 if true
J1:     
        mov edx, 0      ; clear edx 
        inc eax         ; increment eax to begin prime checking
        cmp eax, 100    ; if eax reaches 100 loop ends
        je J2
        push eax
        push edx
        call _isPrime   ; prime check on eax
        cmp  edx, 0     ; if not prime begin loop again
        je J1
        mov [arr], eax  ; if prime eax is stored into array
        jmp J1          ; loop begins again
 
J2:
      
    mov     eax, 0
    ret

_MainProc   ENDP

_isPrime PROC 

        push ebp 
        mov  ebp, esp 
        push ecx
        push ebx

        cmp     eax,1
        jle     L2
        mov     ecx,eax
        shr     ecx,1
        mov     ebx,2
        mov     edx,1
L1:
        cmp     ebx,ecx
        jg      L2
        push    eax
        mov     edx,0
        div     ebx
        cmp     edx,0
        je      L2
        inc     ebx
        jmp     L1
        mov     edx,1
L2:
                      
        pop ebx
        pop ecx
        pop ebp
        ret

_isPrime ENDP            

END
```

Comment: how many times have I said this: use a debugger

Comment: `main` pushes arguments for `isPrime` but nobody pops them.

Comment: `isPrime` also has a `push eax` which isn't matched by a `pop`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the memory being lost".  I think you may have a misunderstanding as to how the stack works.

Comment: By the way, you've tagged this [tag:nasm] but the syntax looks like [tag:masm].  Is that a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>    push eax
>    push edx
>    call _isPrime   ; prime check on eax
> ```

You don't need to supply this `EDX` parameter at all. The *_isPrime* procedure doesn't use it as an argument.
Next you need to balance the stack. You could opt to return from the proc using `ret 4` to pop off the sole argument `EAX` provided at least that the proc fetched it with an instruction like `mov eax, [ebp + 8]`...

> ```
>    mov [arr], eax  ; if prime eax is stored into array
>    jmp J1          ; loop begins again
> ```

You will store every prime on top of the other!

```
    mov edi, offset arr

    ...

    mov [edi], eax
    add edi, 4
    jmp J1
```

This could work.

---

> ```
>   push    eax
>   mov     edx,0
>   div     ebx
>   cmp     edx,0
>   je      L2
> ```

In *_isPrime* you fail to preserve the value in `EAX` because the `pop eax` is missing!

```
push    eax       ; (1)
xor     edx, edx
div     ebx
pop     eax       ; (1)
test    edx, edx
jz      L2
```

For correct operation the `mov edx, 1` instruction needs to go **in** the loop and not **before** the loop:

```
L1:     mov     edx,1
        cmp     ebx,ecx
        jg      L2
```

Comment: Don't forget to setup the `DS` segment register. Something like `mov ax, @data` `mov ds, ax`.